# How do I get the values from the cells of a selected row in a datagrid?

Tags: mvvm, datagrid

I see where this question has been asked but most of the answers seem to center around code behind while I am using an MVVM pattern.  For those answers that pertain to my situation, I have tried a number of different suggestions but I seem to be missing the big picture.

Basically what I am looking to do is add a delete button that would delete all selected rows in the datagrid from an SQL database or add a delete button to each row.  I would prefer to have a single delete button but am open to a delete button in each row, which I have actually already done but still face the same problem in that I need to delete a specific record ID from the database as well as remove it from the collection.

XAML

```
            <DataGrid x:Name="licenseGrid"
                  ItemsSource="{Binding LoggedUsers}"
                  SelectedItem="{Binding SelectedLicense, Mode=TwoWay}"
                  Style="{DynamicResource DataGridStyle}"
                  Grid.Row="2"
                  Grid.Column="1"
                  Grid.ColumnSpan="6"
                  Height="535"
                  VerticalAlignment="Top"
                  IsReadOnly="True"
                  AutoGenerateColumns="False" 
                  HeadersVisibility="Column"
                  SelectionMode="Extended"
                  CanUserDeleteRows="True">
```

ViewModel

```
        public ObservableCollection<MD_LoggedUsersModel> LoggedUsers
    {
        get { return _loggedUsers; }
        set { _loggedUsers = value; NotifyPropertyChanged(nameof(LoggedUsers)); }

        public string SelectedLicense
    {
        get
        {
            return _selectedLicense;
        }
        set
        {
            if (_selectedLicense != value)
            {
                _selectedLicense = value;
                OnPropertyChanged(nameof(SelectedLicense));
                RevokeSelected(_selectedLicense);
            }
            if (_selectedLicense == null)
            {
                LoadData();
            }
        }
    }
```

The value that is being returned is the name of the LoggedUsers model.

How do I get the value of each cell?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You'll need to update your `SelectedItem` to be the same type as the items in your `ObservableColleciton`.

```
public MD_LoggedUsersModel SelectedLicense
{
    get
    {
        return _selectedLicense;
    }
    set
    {
        if (_selectedLicense != value)
        {
            _selectedLicense = value;
        }
    }
}
```